# Regex to match the pattern: something FROM xxxx TO yyyy

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I am working on some text processing for location based services where I want to find out if the input matches the type `something sth FROM xxxx TO yyyy`. Basically I need to find out source and destination that user types.

For example

```
show me how can I go from xxxx to yyyy
I want to go to abcd
I want to go from abcd to xyz
```

I am not strong in regex, The regex that I could come up is `A-Za-z` from `A-Za-z` to `A-Za-z` which is not working. Can anyone please tell me how to match multi keyword regex where words may be separated by any number of words. For example `I want to go FROM manhattan TO Seattle` or `I want to go FROM times square, New York City TO Seattle`. I can extract source/destination by indexing then.

I am able to extract if it contains `FROM` in middle of sentence but I want to make it generic so I don't have to create multiple rules. User may say

```
I want to go TO x FROM y
I want to go FROM x to Y
```

In above sentences the source and the destination get swapped.

Thanks

Comment: Can you guarantee that the city name (e.g., if input by a user) will not contain " to "? Otherwise, there is no way to determine which "to" is part of the name and which is part of the expression.

Comment: @nathanjosiah I have mentioned the regex I tried. Also added screenshot how I am able to get if my input sentence contains the word FROM but I would like to know if FROM comes before or after TO, i.e source is mentioned first or destination first.

Comment: Did you try ".*(from).*(to).*"?

Comment: @brettz9 good catch but I am trying to have spaces before and after keyword TO and currently I dont know any city name with word " to " in its name. I may be wrong and this may need more thought but my guess is this way it would work for most city names.

Comment: @JamesDidzun Thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest one I can think of would be `.*(from).*(to).*`

Comment: Why do you need grouping on the things you know it matches anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use word boundary anchors, or the regex will fail on sentences like

```
I want to go from Montreal to Toronto.
```

Also, you should be capturing the parts between the matchwords, not the matchwords themselves:

```
Pattern regex1 = Pattern.compile(
    "\\b     # Match word boundary\n" +
    "from    # Match 'from'\n" +
    "\\s+    # Match whitespace\n" +
    "(.+?)   # Match one or more characters\n" +
    "\\b     # Match word boundary\n" +
    "to      # Match 'to'\n" +
    "\\s+    # Match whitespace\n" +
    "(.+)    # Match one or more characters", 
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
Pattern regex2 = Pattern.compile("\\bto\\s+(.+?)\\bfrom\\s+(.+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);

Matcher regexMatcher = regex1.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    fromString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    destString = regexMatcher.group(2);
} else {
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex2.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        fromString = regexMatcher.group(1);
        destString = regexMatcher.group(2);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=from\s)(.*)(?<=\sto)(.*)` should work.

Comment: I am coding in Java and it did not understand this syntax, but thanks for your help. Other regex mentioned above is working. Regards